# Printing form with proper margins and scaling while disabling certain objects in VB6

Tags: forms, printing, vb6

Once again, I'm stuck. I've tried figuring out how to print a form while having margins, a proper scaling, and certain objects not visible.

So far, I've tried `.PaintPicture` function which centers the form it prints but that's it (read: you can't disable some objects there), while using `.PrintForm` I can make some objects visible but I couldn't figure it out how to center and scale the form to fit and do some scaling so that the print result doesn't crop the form it prints. Playing with `.Scale` functions (e.g., `.ScaleHeight`, `.ScaleWidth`) apparently obviously don't help either as they give me errors after countless trial, error, and curiosity.

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim NumCopies, I
  'rem  Set Cancel to True
  dlgDialog.CancelError = False
  dlgDialog.Flags = cdlPDUseDevModeCopies 'Enables multiple-copy printing

Dim MarginsLR As Single
Dim MarginsTB As Single
Dim PrintableWidth As Single
Dim PrintableHeight As Single
Dim ScaleFactor As Double
Dim ScaledWidth As Double
Dim ScaledHeight As Double

    MarginsLR = Printer.ScaleX(0.5, vbInches, Printer.ScaleMode)
    MarginsTB = Printer.ScaleY(0.5, vbInches, Printer.ScaleMode)
    PrintableWidth = Printer.Width - 2 * MarginsLR
    PrintableHeight = Printer.Height - 2 * MarginsTB

    ScaleFactor = PrintableWidth / Printer.ScaleX(Form1.Width, vbHiMetric, Printer.ScaleMode)
    If ScaleFactor * Printer.ScaleY(Form1.Height, vbHiMetric, Printer.ScaleMode) > PrintableHeight Then
        ScaleFactor = PrintableHeight / Printer.ScaleY(Form1.Height, vbHiMetric, Printer.ScaleMode)
    End If

    ScaledWidth = ScaleFactor * Printer.ScaleX(Form1.Width, vbHiMetric, Printer.ScaleMode)
    ScaledHeight = ScaleFactor * Printer.ScaleY(Form1.Height, vbHiMetric, Printer.ScaleMode)
    MoveX = (Printer.Width - ScaledWidth) / 2
    MoveY = (Printer.Height - ScaledHeight) / 2

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
' Display the Print dialog box
dlgDialog.ShowPrinter

NumCopies = dlgDialog.Copies
For I = 1 To NumCopies
'The following was experimental
'Form1.ScaleHeight = ScaledHeight
'Form1.ScaleWidth = ScaledWidth
'Form1.ScaleX = MoveX
'Form1.ScaleY = MoveY

'For the .PrintForm function. I can't figure out how to do all the centering stuff sadly...
Label1.Visible = True
Command1.Visible = False

'This following code enables resizing and positioning but it doesn't make both Label1 and Command1 statements above work
Printer.PaintPicture CaptureClient(Me), (Printer.Width - Me.Width) / 2, _
(Printer.Height - Me.Height) / 2
'Form1.PrintForm
Printer.EndDoc
Next I

Label1.Visible = False
Command1.Visible = True
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "The following error has occurred:" & vbNewLine _
& "Err # " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, _
vbCritical, _
"Print Error"
End Sub
```

Your help is appreciated. I'm currently updating my application's normal printing function with the new one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you print the information contained in the form directly or do you actually need the form?

Comment: I actually just need the form. The information inside the print function are just notes to give some heads-up.